Springboot Deployment error in github action through azure web app
I am trying to deploy a springboot application to azure web app through github action but it showing me an error:
 Error:  Errors:  Error:    SchoolManagementAppApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@35c00c testClass = com.sro.demo.SchoolManagementAppApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.sro.demo.SchoolManagementAppApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@53fb3dab, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@742ff096, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@68c9133c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@59402b8f, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@201795de], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
 Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test (default-test) on project demo:  Error:   Error:  Please refer to /home/runner/work/SMA-Backend/SMA-Backend/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results. Error:  Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream. Error:  -> [Help 1] Error:   Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. Error:   Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
I am using local mysql database but the database is not hosted in azure. But it is optional to be hosted i think.
here is my pom.xml
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=@Swasti123456
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=9091

and this is the github action yaml file
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App - smabackend

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'microsoft'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar'

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write # This is required for requesting the JWT

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '@Swasti123456'
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'school'
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping -h mysql --silent" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: java-app

      - name: Wait for MySQL to be ready
        run: |
          until docker exec mysql mysqladmin -u root -p@Swasti123456 ping --silent; do  # Make sure the password is correctly handled
            echo "Waiting for MySQL to be ready..."
            sleep 5
          done

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_716E375332574749B1E5827D5444A976 }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_36963E91F39546E2BE59575A5A9161FD }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_E4BE32CC9689446CA8D856EA940F1928 }}

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'smabackend'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: '*.jar'


I am trying to deploy the springboot application to azure but it is showing error in github action.

Provide your code or GitHub repository link if possible.

I doubt that during tests you have a running mysql instance. You have specified a JDBC url so the datatbase is mandatory to run your application and it needs to be accesible on localhost.

Remove Server.Port=9091 in application.properties.
Increase the sleep time in GitHub workflow.
- name: Wait for MySQL to be ready
  run: |
    until docker exec mysql user -u root -password ping --silent; do
      echo "Waiting for MySQL to be ready..."
      sleep 10
    done

Looks like the error you are getting when running the tests in a Spring Boot application as there is a failure in loading the application context, which could be due to misconfiguration, missing dependencies.
Configure the necessary annotations and check the configuration in your Spring boot application.
I have created a simple spring boot application with H2 database.
application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/user
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true

Try using my GitHub workflow:
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'microsoft'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar'

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
      
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: java-app
      
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'appname'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: '*.jar'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_8B922BXXXAAFEFDB86 }}

Deployment Status:

Response:

